# combining lists of tuples

Tags: python, tuples

I have 11 files, each of which contain students, and scores for each students. Like this:

File 1: 
(A, 3)
(B, 4)
(C, 1)
(D, 2)
(E, 6)
(F, 1)

File 2: 
(A, 8)
(B, 3)
(C, 4)
(D, 2)
etc.,

I now want to make a counter which iterates over all 11 files and adds and sorts the value for all keys, so that I would have something like this:

(A, 11) (B, 7) (E, 6) (C, 5) (D, 4) (F, 1)

I used the following code, but this one does not combine the values from the different files:

```
import os                                                                   
import glob                                                                 
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

for file in list(glob.glob('*.txt')):                                       
    scores = []
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        name, score = line.split(' ')
        score = int(score)
        scores.append((name, score))


##this is the part where it is all about:
dict_1 = dict(scores)
all_keys = []
all_keys += set(dict_1.keys())
sum_list = [(k, dict_1.get(k, 0)) for k in all_keys]
print sorted(sum_list, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

Is there a way I could add the keys and values from the different files together in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this. It'll handle combining the data and allow you to conveniently sort them from highest to lowest value. Also, I think you have a slight indentation problem in your file-reading block.

```
import glob
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()

for filename in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    with open(filename) as file:
        for line in file:
            name, score = line.split(' ')
            counter[name] += int(score)

print counter.most_common()
```

Comment: Thanks! This was extremely helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution, but try this (assuming that the pairs from both files are in a list `scores`):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for s in scores:
    d[s[0]] += s[1]

print d
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this'll do:

```
import os                                                                   
import glob                                                                 
from collections import defaultdict

score_sums = defaultdict(int)

for file_name in list(glob.glob('*.txt')):                                       
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            name, score = line.split(' ')
            score = int(score)
            score_sums[name] += score

print sorted(score_sums, key=lambda k:score_sums[k], reverse=True)
```

I fixed the indentation and simplified the whole thing a bit by using a `defaultdict` which you were already importing. I also replaced your `itemgetter` with a `lambda` but that's just a matter of habit. Finally, I changed `file` to `file_name` since `file` is a built-in type.

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary and summing the score corresponding to each key as you parse the files would work. Try something like this:

```
import os                                                                   
import glob                                                                 
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

scores = defaultdict(int)
for file in list(glob.glob('*.txt')):                                      
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            tuples = line.split(' ')
            for elem in tuples:
                name, score = tuple(elem[1:-1].split(','))
                score = int(score)
                scores[name] += score

print scores
```

Also, if you want to split on the space character like `split(' ')`, your files should contain the data like this:
`(A,3) (B,4) (C,1) (D,2) (E,6) (F,1)` - without a space after the comma between each element of the tuple.